# Java while loop problems

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a while loop that isn't executing.  I don't believe there is an infinite loop or priming problem, but is there?  I can't find my logical error!

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        int i = 1;
        int j = 1;
        while  ((i < 10) && (j*j != 25));
        { 
           i++;  
           ++j;
           System.out.println( i * j );
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Remove the semicolon after the while loop

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
     int i = 1;
     int j = 1;
     while  ((i < 10) && (j*j != 25)) //Semicolon removed from here
     { 
        i++;  
        ++j;
        System.out.println( i * j );
     }   
}
```

Any statement that directly comes after the loop declaration is considered the whole block if it's not enclosed with braces.

I.E

```
if( true ) 
    System.out.println( "hello" );
    System.out.println( "world" );
```

Is treated as

```
if( true ) {
     System.out.println( "hello" );
}
System.out.println( "world" );
```

A single semicolon is considered as [empty statement](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/In_java_what_is_empty_statement.Explain_its_usefulness) and thus made up your whole loop body.

Comment: Almost a +1. It needs an explanation of why this fixes the problem.

Comment: he also had an infinite loop, even though he was not thinking so